# Where should I declare functions that are called inside a useEffect() hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

So I have the following situation when using a `useEffect` that calls a functions that depends on state.

**Example:**

```
// INSIDE APP COMPONENT

const [someState, setSomeState] = React.useState(0);
const [someTrigger, setSomeTrigger] = React.useState(false);

function someFunction() {
  return someState + 1;  
}

React.useEffect(() => {

  const newState = someFunction();  // 'someFunction' IS BEING CALLED HERE
  setSomeState(newState);

},[someTrigger])
```

**QUESTIONS:**

In this case, should I declare `someFunction` inside the `useEffect()` or is it safe to keep it outside (but inside component's body)?

I could add it to the `dependency` array, but it will hurt the redability of my code, since I want to focus on the `trigger`.

Since the `useEffect()` will run after a fresh render, **is it safe to assume that it will have fresh copies of the functions that I'm calling inside of it?**

Is there a basic rule of when you should declare functions inside the `useEffect` hook or when is it mandatory that you add it to the dependency array?

**EDIT:** Note that it's necessary that the `useEffect` has fresh copies of those functions, since those functions need to access some fresh up-to-date `state` variable.

**NOTE:**

This code triggers the following **eslint warning** on CodeSandbox. Although it works just fine.

> React Hook React.useEffect has a missing dependency: 'someFunction'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. (react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)eslint

**REAL CASE SCENARIO:**

This is a simplified example. In my real case, this is a product search page with filters components. So when I click on a filter to activate it (let's say, `price <= 50`), I'm triggering a `useEffect()` that is "listening" for the `activePriceFilters` state variable. That effect then calls a function (`someFunction` in the example) that will calculate the `filteredList` and will set the new `productList` state with the new `filteredList`.

**SNIPPET**

```js
function App() {
  
  const [someState, setSomeState] = React.useState(0);
  const [someTrigger, setSomeTrigger] = React.useState(false);
  
  function someFunction() {
    return someState + 1;  
  }
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
  
    const newState = someFunction();
    setSomeState(newState);
  
  },[someTrigger])
  
  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>I am App</div>
      <div>My state: {someState}</div>
      <button onClick={()=>setSomeTrigger((prevState) => !prevState)}>Click</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: You can read [this FAQ answer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies). Also, [this is an awesome article](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) about `useEffect`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A decision to define a function within or outside of useEffect depends on where all the functions is called.

If your function is called only from within the useEffect then it makes sense to define it within the useEffect.

However is the same function is being called from within useEffect as well as other event handlers or other effects, you need to define it outside of useEffect

PS. in your case you are just updating the state for which you needn't define a separate function

```js
function App() {
  
  const [someState, setSomeState] = React.useState(0);
  const [someTrigger, setSomeTrigger] = React.useState(false);
  

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setSomeState(oldState => oldState + 1);
  
  },[someTrigger])
  
  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>I am App</div>
      <div>My state: {someState}</div>
      <button onClick={()=>setSomeTrigger((prevState) => !prevState)}>Click</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

As far as you scenario is concerned, you would write it like

```
useEffect(() => {
    const calcVal = (oldState) => {
         // calculate previous state based on oldState
    }

    setSomeState(calcVal);
}, [activePriceFilters])
```

Comment: The example is an over simplified version of my real case scenario.

Comment: Can you help with my real case scenario? It's a product search page with filters components. So when I click on a filter to activate it (let's say, price <= 50), I'm triggering a useEffect() that is "listening" for the activePriceFilters state variable. That effect then calls a function (someFunction in the example) that will calculate the filteredList and will set the new productList state with the new filteredList. Is there anything wrong with this approach? How would you handle this? Thanks!

Comment: As I said, you need to define a separate function outside of useEffect if the function will be used outside of useEffect, else define it within useEffect and pass it on to state update

Comment: Thanks! But from my overall code pattern, do you think it's a good approach? Using a `useEffect` to "listen" for change in the state filters variable and call a function that sets a new state for the `filteredList` ? Sorry to bother you. Your answer was really helpful.

Comment: Doesn't declaring functions inside the useEffect mean they are re-created every time the useEffect is triggered? Or is the Javascript runtime smart enough to cache them or something?

Answer (score 1):

Setting another state should not be an effect at all.

```
 const [someState, setSomeState] = React.useState(0);

 function incrementState() {
    setSomeState(someState => someState + 1);
 }
```

Comment: Can you help with my real case scenario? It's a product search page with filters components. So when I click on a filter to activate it (let's say, `price <= 50`), I'm triggering a `useEffect()` that is "listening" for the `activePriceFilters` state variable. That effect then calls a function (`someFunction` in the example) that will calculate the `filteredList` and will set the new `productList` state with the new `filteredList`. Is there anything wrong with this approach? How would you handle this? Thanks!

Comment: Does it calculate them synchronously? Or does it retrieve them from a server?

Comment: It is synchronous. I should also add that I have more than 1 component filter, and more then one state variable with different active filters. If any of them change, I should calculate a new `filteredList` state that is passed down as props to my `ResultList` component.

Comment: Then I'd just do `const [filters, setFilters] = useState([]); const result = data.filter(filters /*...*/);`

Comment: And what if it were asynchronous? Would you do it inside a `useEffect` then? Like: `useEffect(()=>{ // Activate Loading State // Await for async call // Deactivate Loading state // },[activeFilter] );` Something like that?

Comment: Yes, in that case.

Answer (score 0):

From performance point of view.

Declaring functions inside the useEffect hook will cause them to be recreated every time the useEffect is triggered.

When you declare a function inside the useEffect hook, it gets redefined each time the component is rendered, as the useEffect hook runs after every render where its dependency array changes. This behavior can lead to unnecessary overhead, particularly if the function doesn't rely on any external variables within the useEffect.