# React hooks equivalent of componentDidCatch?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a simple component that acts as an error boundary in my React app, and which passes off any errors to a logging service.

It looks something like this:

```
export class CatchError extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    hasError: false
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, info) {
    this.props.log({ error, info })
    this.setState({ hasError: true })
  }

  render() {
    const child = typeof this.props.children === "function"
      ? this.props.children({ error: hasError })
      : children

    return React.cloneElement(child, { error: this.state.hasError })
  }
}
```

Is there a React hook equivalent to `componentDidCatch` so I can make this component a function and not a class?

So it might look something like this:

```
export function CatchError({ children, log }) {
  const [hasError, setHasError] = useState(false)
  const caught = useDidCatch()

  useEffect(() => {
    const [error, info] = caught
    log({ error, info })
    setHasError(true)
  }, [caught])

  const child = typeof children === "function"
    ? children({ error: hasError })
    : children

  return React.cloneElement(child, { error: hasError })
}
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

There is not a React hook equivalent of `componentDidCatch`.

However, the React team plans to add one soon.

The React docs state:

> There are no Hook equivalents to the uncommon getSnapshotBeforeUpdate and componentDidCatch lifecycles yet, but we plan to add them soon.

Read more: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#do-hooks-cover-all-use-cases-for-classes

Comment: It says "but we plan to add them soon.", But it doesn't seem to be implemented yet. Do you know if there was any problem?

Comment: "No specific time commitment. When we have a good API. :-) These should be fairly uncommon anyway"
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/19630#issuecomment-675390931

Answer (score 23):

There is not any official hook for [Error Boundaries](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html)(componentDidCatch) in react.
but you can simply use [try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) to catch component errors like this:

```js
function myComponent(...) {
  // Initialize state variables.
  // Initialize context variables.
  // Initialize custom hooks.
  // ...

  try {
    // Define internal functions.
    // Define internal variables.

    return (
      <SomeThing />
    )
  } catch (error) {
    // Catch internal functions, variables and return (jsx) errors.
    // You can also create a lib to log the error to an error reporting service
    // and use it here.
  }
}
```

The `try...catch` block is the **Error Boundry** here.

**Limitation**:
when you use a hook like `useEffect` and you use some `internal functions` in it, you cannot put that internal function into try...catch(Error Boundary) block because you should define that function on top of useEffect hook ([why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56850196/where-should-i-declare-functions-that-are-called-inside-a-useeffect-hook)) and you shouldn't use useEffect conditionally ([why?](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level))!

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-u43gf?file=/src/index.tsx

Comment: @jeiea This is not exactly what I said. you should use try...catch inside Bomb to catch errors (there isn't a service like error boundaries which you use once forever. you should use try...catch everywhere you want to catch errors and send it to an external service)

Comment: This approach is actually discouraged explicitly in the official doc. https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html

Comment: no, it is not @MikeFeltman.
they said `try / catch is great but it only works for imperative code` and I also mentioned the limitations of this approach!

Comment: "try / catch is great but it only works for imperative code ... However, React components are declarative and specify what should be rendered"

Comment: I understand the answer and use a similar technique in my code. It's not quite the same thing as componentDidCatch or creating an error boundary, but it is as close as we can get in a functional component right now.

Comment: @MikeFeltman Exactly! also as you see my answer to this question was `There is not any official hook for Error Boundaries(componentDidCatch) in react.` and the others was `to catch component errors`. I believe *-1* is unfair ;)

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned already, the React team has [not yet implemented a hook equivalent](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#do-hooks-cover-all-use-cases-for-classes), and there are [no published timelines](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/19630#issuecomment-675390931) for a hook implementation.

A few third party packages on npm implement error boundary hooks. This is the [most popular npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-error-boundary). Alternatively, I published [react-use-error-boundary](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-use-error-boundary), attempting to recreate an API similar to [useErrorBoundary from Preact](https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/hooks/#useerrorboundary).