# Cant put response.data into my React.js state?(express.js)

Tags: reactjs, express, react-hooks, react-state

```
    export default function Main({ match }) {
  const userid = match.params.id;
  const [user, setUser] = useState([]);
  async function fetchuser() {
    const response = await api.get('/emps/profile', {
      headers: {
        userid: match.params.id,
      },
    });
    setUser(response.data);
    console.log(response.data);
    console.log(user);
}
 useEffect(() => {
    
    fetchuser();
  }, [match.params.id]);
```

In the above code the response.data is written into console but user state is empty. Can someone tell me why this is?

Comment: This may be due to the asynchronous nature of `useState`. Your state is not going to be immediately set.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

1. Determine if `response` contains any data before logging it.
2. Move your `fetchData` function into the `useEffect` hook. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56851963/8943092

Below is an example of how you can test for the existence of data, and here is a [live Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-feynman-517qw?file=/src/App.js).

Note that we use a simple conditional to check `if (myData)` is truthy. Our useState hook sets no default value, so the conditional returns `true` once data is present.

In the render method, we [use a ternary](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) to check for the existence of data.

Your solution may be slightly different because you set the default value of `user` to an empty array `[]`. Assuming your API call returns an array, you'll test for data with `if (user.length > 0)`.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [myData, setMyData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    function fetchData() {
      setTimeout(function () {
        setMyData("I am user data");
      }, 3000);
    }

    if (myData) {
      console.log(myData);
    } else {
      console.log("No data yet");
    }

    fetchData();
  }, [myData]);
  return (
    <div className="App">{myData ? <p>{myData}</p> : <p>No data yet</p>}</div>
  );
}
```